# Error Message when activate Business Messages API in the API Library for your GCP project

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api

Google processed my Business Messages partner registration and my project has already get Partner ID and Partner Project.

But when I try to activate API in library from this url: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/library/businessmessages.googleapis.com
I've got the error:

An error occurred while loading

```
/apis/library/businessmessages.googleapis.com?project=mybusiness-152610&folder=&organizationId=.
```

> Try again.
> ID request : 3154477086545573582

I don't know what's wrong, if someone has an idea how to avoid it please, I already follow all steps in their documentation

Thank you so much

Comment: To proceed further can you please let us know what are the steps and links you followed in order to build the API.

Comment: Hello,
Thank you
Here is the link that contains the steps that I followed : https://developers.google.com/business-communications/business-messages/guides/quickstarts/prerequisite-setup.
1) sign up https://console.cloud.google.com/
2) register with the project's number as Partner
3) Google accepts the partner and gives me the partner ID and the partner key
4) Enable Business Message API:Open the url https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/businessmessages.googleapis.com

Answer (score 0):

I just read the mail from Google BM-support again and found this.
"We have granted your email address access to the Business Messages API, Business Communications API". I think if your cloud account isn't same as the email you were granted, then you can't search Business Message API.

And it said ...
"Please reply to this email, or send a new email to bm-support@google.com, to request access for additional email addresses."

Maybe you can try to write a mail to bm-support@google.com ..
I'll do it.